# Categorise date into accounting month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Create a table which contains the region with highest percentage change in sales for each accounting month. (An accounting month M is defined as period between 15th of month M to 14th of month M+1. Ex : accounting month May '20 begins on 15th May '20 and ends on 14th June '20)

Sample Input data

```
Date         Region   Accounting Month
01-01-2019    North          Dec'18
14-01-2019    South          Dec'18
20-01-2019    West           Jan'19
04-02-2019    North          Jan'19
```

I tried the following code

```
df['Accounting Month'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1) + pd.DateOffset(days=14)
```

But it is providing inaccurate results

Comment: You are facing this issue because the command pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1) changes the date to the start of the current month if the date is later than the 14th aand to the beginning of the last month if the date is before the 15th. After that pd.DateOffset(days=14) adds 14 days to this date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table 'df':

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['01-01-2019', '14-01-2019', '20-01-2019', '04-02-2019'],
    'Region': ['North', 'South', 'West', 'North']
})
```

Create your function:

```
def calculate_accounting_month(date):
    if date.day >= 15:
        return f"{date.strftime('%b')}\'{str(date.year)[2:]}"
    else:
        previous_month_date = date - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
        return f"{previous_month_date.strftime('%b')}\'{str(previous_month_date.year)[2:]}"
```

Formate Date column:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Call the dunction:

```
df['Accounting Month'] = df['Date'].apply(calculate_accounting_month)
```

Comment: This gives the accounting month and it is spot on further how do we calculate the highest % change in sales for each accounting month if there is a slaes column

Comment: you should provide more information regarding sales

Comment: You did not mention Sales related column. I cannot give you the whole code without knowing your sales

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Serie.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for months periods with subtract `1` if days is bellow `15` and convert to expected ouput by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)  

df['Accounting Month'] = (df['Date'].dt.to_period('m')
                                    .sub(np.where(df['Date'].dt.day < 15, 1, 0))
                                    .dt.strftime("%b'%y"))
print (df)
        Date Region Accounting Month
0 2019-01-01  North           Dec'18
1 2019-01-14  South           Dec'18
2 2019-01-20   West           Jan'19
3 2019-02-04  North           Jan'19
```

Next it depends what need, here is count percentage change per `Region` and `Accounting Month` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
print (df)
        Date Region  Data
0 2019-01-01  South    12
1 2019-01-02  South    10
2 2019-01-14  South    45
3 2019-01-15   West     4
4 2019-02-04   West     5

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)  

df['Accounting Month'] = (df['Date'].dt.to_period('m')
                                    .sub(np.where(df['Date'].dt.day < 15, 1, 0))
                                    .dt.strftime("%b'%y"))

df['pctchange'] = df.groupby(['Accounting Month','Region'])['Data'].pct_change()
print (df)
        Date Region  Data Accounting Month  pctchange
0 2019-01-01  South    12           Dec'18        NaN
1 2019-01-02  South    10           Dec'18  -0.166667
2 2019-01-14  South    45           Dec'18   3.500000
3 2019-01-15   West     4           Jan'19        NaN
4 2019-02-04   West     5           Jan'19   0.250000
```

And then get rows per maximal `Data` per `Accounting Month` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby('Accounting Month')['pctchange'].idxmax()]
print (out)
        Date Region  Data Accounting Month  pctchange
2 2019-01-14  South    45           Dec'18       3.50
4 2019-02-04   West     5           Jan'19       0.25
```